# File not found - sitio Drupal usado desde WSL2

Tags: php, linux, docker, drupal, wsl

Estoy empezando a trabajar en un sitio hecho con **Drupal** desde el subsistema **WSL2** ya que este sitio usa las herramientas *ddev* y *docker*.

Actualmente estoy teniendo un problema con su instalación. Al querer arrancar el sitio con *ddev start* este inicia sin problemas, pero al entrar a la url del sitio, me redirige a *core/install.php* y no encuentra ningun archivo del sitio, por lo cual en la página solo carga el siguiente error: **"file not found"**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna idea de cuál podrá ser el problema? Tendrá algo que ver con configurar bien el host de linux o algo? Ya que lo ejecuto desde windows y si funciona, pero carga mas lento por ddev, por eso el querer ejecutarlo desde WSL2.

Comment: Instalaste y configuraste nginx con wls? https://websiteforstudents.com/how-to-install-drupal-on-windows-wsl/

Comment: @Cuauhtli graciasss jajajaj, si lo tenia instalado pero gracias a eso que me dijiste me di cuenta que no se enlazaba por que el puerto 8080 ya estaba ocupado por mysql de windows, y se lo cambie a nginx